# How to get 2 different department to discuss and clarify their scope work on a service that I receive from them?

Tags: management

I am an internal customer that receive a report between the HR & IT departments.  However, this report is often incomplete or I have to string together multiple reports to get what I need.  The issue is that this report requires both HR & IT's input but neither department would like to take on the entire task (more work for that department), end result, incomplete reports from individual department or sometimes no reports at all as they think the other department is already doing it and the report is good enough.  I am not their boss, any ideas to solve this issue?  Perhaps suggest to have the two department's managers have a talk?  I am not sure I am really the person or in position to do that either.  Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is straightforward: write down your exact requirements for the reports, then organise a meeting between the three concerned parties. Explain to HR and IT what your requirements are and ask them to discuss which of them should provide it. Perhaps it's even possible for them both to work together and combine it all into a single report.

Comment: And if this does not work, this is an issue that should be discussed between your boss and their bosses, and if it still does not work out, possibly even including the "smallest common denominator" in the chain of command... whoever that is, possibly the CEO himself.